python - how to load image from pyautogui.screenshot to qLabel (pyqt5)
How to load screenshot from img to qLabel without saving image
#pyqt5
def click_screenBtn():
    try:
        img = pyautogui.screenshot('screen.png')
        w.qLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap('screen.png'))
    except:
        print(w.log.append('except error'))

something like this:
 img = pyautogui.screenshot()
 img = img.toqpixmap()
 w.qLabel.setPixmap(img)

trying many variants, but all of them crushed. I can't find the right data type

from PIL.ImageQt import ImageQt; pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(ImageQt(pyautogui.screenshot())).

this is didn't work for me,
pyCharm highlights the text: Expected type 'QImage', got 'ImageQT' instead
and I have Exception from this code: fromImage(image: QImage, flags: Union[Qt.ImageConversionFlags, Qt.ImageConversionFlag] = Qt.AutoColor): argument 1 has unexpected type 'ImageQt'

The problem is that the version of PIL that pyautogui uses returns PyQt6 classes, which obviously aren't compatible with PyQt5 (see here). If you don't want to switch to PyQt6, you can use the following work-around: from io import BytesIO; data = BytesIO(); img = pyautogui.screenshot(); img.save(data, 'png'); pixmap = QPixmap.fromImage(QImage.fromData(data.getvalue())).

thanks ekhumoro, very grateful for the help, this is what I needed and it code works
